# Using Dart in Angular (NOT AngularDart) using dart2js

Tags: angular, dart

I have an Angular app in production for which I'm planning to build native apps using Flutter. To have code re-use, I was thinking of isolating the non-UI logic into Dart code and share it between the web and native apps.

Would it be possible to use this Dart code within the existing Angular app by compiling it to JS using dart2js? I do not want to convert the web app into AngularDart.

Comment: I'd say it's theoretically possible, but not practical. You you could communicate between Angular (TS) and Dart using `sendMessage` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, I'm planning to start coding the common logic in Dart first because I need to do that anyway. My hope is that Google will release Hummingbird soon (hopefully by Google I/O), so I won't need to mess with AngularDart at all. I will post back my experience.